# I am getting Undefined property: stdClass

Tags: php, laravel

I have an object name `event` I am trying to get one of it's property named `event` but I am getting this error

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$event
```

This is how I am accessing it

`echo $event->event;`

when I try to `var_dump` this `$event` I get this as result

```
object(stdClass)#198 (4) {
  ["event"]=>
  string(8) "deferral"
  ["msg"]=>
  object(stdClass)#462 (12) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(1365109999)
    ["subject"]=>
    string(31) "This an example webhook message"
    ["email"]=>
    string(31) "example.webhook@mandrillapp.com"
    ["sender"]=>
    string(30) "example.sender@mandrillapp.com"
    ["tags"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(15) "webhook-example"
    }
    ["opens"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["clicks"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["state"]=>
    string(8) "deferred"
    ["metadata"]=>
    object(stdClass)#487 (1) {
      ["user_id"]=>
      int(111)
    }
    ["_id"]=>
    string(32) "exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    ["_version"]=>
    string(22) "exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    ["smtp_events"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#483 (6) {
        ["destination_ip"]=>
        string(9) "127.0.0.1"
        ["diag"]=>
        string(51) "451 4.3.5 Temporarily unavailable, try again later."
        ["source_ip"]=>
        string(9) "127.0.0.1"
        ["ts"]=>
        int(1365111111)
        ["type"]=>
        string(8) "deferred"
        ["size"]=>
        int(0)
      }
    }
  }
  ["_id"]=>
  string(32) "exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
  ["ts"]=>
  int(1433587083)
}
```

This is how I am creating an array of `$data` and then using a foreach loop to iterate it as `$event`

```
$data = array (
              'mandrill_events' => '[{"event":"deferral","msg":{"ts":1365109999,"subject":"This an example webhook message","email":"example.webhook@mandrillapp.com","sender":"example.sender@mandrillapp.com","tags":["webhook-example"],"opens":[],"clicks":[],"state":"deferred","metadata":{"user_id":111},"_id":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","_version":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","smtp_events":[{"destination_ip":"127.0.0.1","diag":"451 4.3.5 Temporarily unavailable, try again later.","source_ip":"127.0.0.1","ts":1365111111,"type":"deferred","size":0}]},"_id":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","ts":1433587083},{"event":"hard_bounce","msg":{"ts":1365109999,"subject":"This an example webhook message","email":"example.webhook@mandrillapp.com","sender":"example.sender@mandrillapp.com","tags":["webhook-example"],"state":"bounced","metadata":{"user_id":111},"_id":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1","_version":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","bounce_description":"bad_mailbox","bgtools_code":10,"diag":"smtp;550 5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try double-checking the recipient\'s email address for typos or unnecessary spaces."},"_id":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1","ts":1433587083},{"event":"soft_bounce","msg":{"ts":1365109999,"subject":"This an example webhook message","email":"example.webhook@mandrillapp.com","sender":"example.sender@mandrillapp.com","tags":["webhook-example"],"state":"soft-bounced","metadata":{"user_id":111},"_id":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa2","_version":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","bounce_description":"mailbox_full","bgtools_code":22,"diag":"smtp;552 5.2.2 Over Quota"},"_id":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa2","ts":1433587083},{"event":"open","msg":{"ts":1365109999,"subject":"This an example webhook message","email":"example.webhook@mandrillapp.com","sender":"example.sender@mandrillapp.com","tags":["webhook-example"],"opens":[{"ts":1365111111}],"clicks":[{"ts":1365111111,"url":"http:\\/\\/mandrill.com"}],"state":"sent","metadata":{"user_id":111},"_id":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa3","_version":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},"_id":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa3","ip":"127.0.0.1","location":{"country_short":"US","country":"United States","region":"Oklahoma","city":"Oklahoma City","latitude":35.4675598145,"longitude":-97.5164337158,"postal_code":"73101","timezone":"-05:00"},"user_agent":"Mozilla\\/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko\\/20100317 Postbox\\/1.1.3","user_agent_parsed":{"type":"Email Client","ua_family":"Postbox","ua_name":"Postbox 1.1.3","ua_version":"1.1.3","ua_url":"http:\\/\\/www.postbox-inc.com\\/","ua_company":"Postbox, Inc.","ua_company_url":"http:\\/\\/www.postbox-inc.com\\/","ua_icon":"http:\\/\\/cdn.mandrill.com\\/img\\/email-client-icons\\/postbox.png","os_family":"OS X","os_name":"OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard","os_url":"http:\\/\\/www.apple.com\\/osx\\/","os_company":"Apple Computer, Inc.","os_company_url":"http:\\/\\/www.apple.com\\/","os_icon":"http:\\/\\/cdn.mandrill.com\\/img\\/email-client-icons\\/macosx.png","mobile":false},"ts":1433587083},{"event":"click","msg":{"ts":1365109999,"subject":"This an example webhook message","email":"example.webhook@mandrillapp.com","sender":"example.sender@mandrillapp.com","tags":["webhook-example"],"opens":[{"ts":1365111111}],"clicks":[{"ts":1365111111,"url":"http:\\/\\/mandrill.com"}],"state":"sent","metadata":{"user_id":111},"_id":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa4","_version":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},"_id":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa4","ip":"127.0.0.1","location":{"country_short":"US","country":"United States","region":"Oklahoma","city":"Oklahoma City","latitude":35.4675598145,"longitude":-97.5164337158,"postal_code":"73101","timezone":"-05:00"},"user_agent":"Mozilla\\/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko\\/20100317 Postbox\\/1.1.3","user_agent_parsed":{"type":"Email Client","ua_family":"Postbox","ua_name":"Postbox 1.1.3","ua_version":"1.1.3","ua_url":"http:\\/\\/www.postbox-inc.com\\/","ua_company":"Postbox, Inc.","ua_company_url":"http:\\/\\/www.postbox-inc.com\\/","ua_icon":"http:\\/\\/cdn.mandrill.com\\/img\\/email-client-icons\\/postbox.png","os_family":"OS X","os_name":"OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard","os_url":"http:\\/\\/www.apple.com\\/osx\\/","os_company":"Apple Computer, Inc.","os_company_url":"http:\\/\\/www.apple.com\\/","os_icon":"http:\\/\\/cdn.mandrill.com\\/img\\/email-client-icons\\/macosx.png","mobile":false},"url":"http:\\/\\/mandrill.com","ts":1433587083},{"event":"spam","msg":{"ts":1365109999,"subject":"This an example webhook message","email":"example.webhook@mandrillapp.com","sender":"example.sender@mandrillapp.com","tags":["webhook-example"],"opens":[{"ts":1365111111}],"clicks":[{"ts":1365111111,"url":"http:\\/\\/mandrill.com"}],"state":"sent","metadata":{"user_id":111},"_id":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa5","_version":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},"_id":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa5","ts":1433587083},{"event":"unsub","msg":{"ts":1365109999,"subject":"This an example webhook message","email":"example.webhook@mandrillapp.com","sender":"example.sender@mandrillapp.com","tags":["webhook-example"],"opens":[{"ts":1365111111}],"clicks":[{"ts":1365111111,"url":"http:\\/\\/mandrill.com"}],"state":"sent","metadata":{"user_id":111},"_id":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa6","_version":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},"_id":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa6","ts":1433587083},{"event":"reject","msg":{"ts":1365109999,"subject":"This an example webhook message","email":"example.webhook@mandrillapp.com","sender":"example.sender@mandrillapp.com","tags":["webhook-example"],"opens":[],"clicks":[],"state":"rejected","metadata":{"user_id":111},"_id":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa7","_version":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},"_id":"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa7","ts":1433587083},{"type":"blacklist","action":"add","reject":{"reason":"hard-bounce","detail":"Example detail","last_event_at":"2014-02-01 12:43:56","email":"example.webhook@mandrillapp.com","created_at":"2014-01-15 11:32:19","expires_at":"2020-04-02 12:09:18","expired":false,"subaccount":"example_subaccount","sender":"example.sender@mandrillapp.com"},"ts":1433587083},{"type":"blacklist","action":"change","reject":{"reason":"hard-bounce","detail":"Example detail","last_event_at":"2014-02-01 12:43:56","email":"example.webhook@mandrillapp.com","created_at":"2014-01-15 11:32:19","expires_at":"2020-04-02 12:09:18","expired":false,"subaccount":"example_subaccount","sender":"example.sender@mandrillapp.com"},"ts":1433587083},{"type":"blacklist","action":"remove","reject":{"reason":"hard-bounce","detail":"Example detail","last_event_at":"2014-02-01 12:43:56","email":"example.webhook@mandrillapp.com","created_at":"2014-01-15 11:32:19","expires_at":"2020-04-02 12:09:18","expired":false,"subaccount":"example_subaccount","sender":"example.sender@mandrillapp.com"},"ts":1433587083},{"type":"whitelist","action":"add","entry":{"email":"example.webhook@mandrillapp.com","detail":"example details","created_at":"2014-01-15 12:03:19"},"ts":1433587083},{"type":"whitelist","action":"remove","entry":{"email":"example.webhook@mandrillapp.com","detail":"example details","created_at":"2014-01-15 12:03:19"},"ts":1433587083}]',
            );
$data = json_decode($data['mandrill_events']);
```

Like this

```
foreach ($data as $event) {
    echo $event->event;
}
```

What am doing wrong here?

Comment: initialise  `$event = new stdClass;`  before assigning dynamic properties

Comment: Please post the code that is creating the `$event` object.

Comment: @Bogdan I just updated my question - thanks for the response

Comment: Tried to run your code, getting "deferralhard_bounce" as a result - it works, there is no undefined property error.

Comment: @amik I didn't put the complete array to shorten the question so just updated it with the full version - Can you please update `$data` with the new values and try again? It's somehow working for the short version but not for the complete one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You problem here is that not all objects decoded from the JSON string have the `event` property. So for the ones that don't, you get the undefined property notice. You can check if the object has a property using the [`property_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) function like so:

```
foreach ($data as $event)
{
    if (property_exists($event, 'event'))
        echo $event->event;
}
```

This will avoid the undefined property notice, but if you'd like to handle the case where that happens, you can add an `else` block to the condition.

Comment: I should have asked this 2 hours ago - I feel so stupid, thanks Bogdan

Comment: @Bogdan This fixed the problem but now how do i take the data because when i do DD i see the data but when i do property_exist it doesn't exist?

Comment: @FlyingAtom your question might be different from this one. I suggest you ask a separate question and include the desired behavior and data.

Comment: I had to check for missing value in a loop because not everything has got a value